# Jackson Schema Validator com.github.fge.Frozen Class not found Exception

Tags: schema, jackson, validation

I am using jackson schema validator with the following code:

```
 ObjectMapper mapperSchema = new ObjectMapper();
 ObjectMapper mapperData = new ObjectMapper();
 JsonFactory factory = mapperData.getFactory();             
 JsonParser jp = factory.createParser(jsonDataString);
 JsonNode jsonData = mapperData.readTree(jp);       
 factory = mapperSchema.getFactory();           
 jp = factory.createParser(jsonSchemaString);
 JsonNode jsonSchema = mapperSchema.readTree(jp);

 JsonSchemaFactory schemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
 JsonSchema schema = schemaFactory.getJsonSchema(jsonSchema);

 ProcessingReport report;
 report = schema.validate(jsonData);
```

And when running I am getting the below exception:
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/Frozen
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at gov.max.service.persistence.restlet.resources.data.LibraryDataKeyResource.validateAndGetData(Unknown Source)
    at gov.max.service.persistence.restlet.resources.data.LibraryDataKeyResource.requestGet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

I am using the following three jars
     jackson-annotations-2.2.0.jar
     jackson-core-2.2.0.jar
     jackson-databind-2.2.0.jar

Can you please suggest on what extra do I need to do to get pass that exception.

Thanks in advance,
gvr

Comment: Did u find the solution ? Then please write it

Comment: You are missing BT.jar. Go through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328472/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-github-fge-frozen-while-va?noredirect=1#comment33932698_22328472)