# Getting Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/Frozen while validating json schema using json-schema-validator 2.1.8

Tags: java, validation, jsonschema

I am trying to validate json using json schema validator and am using the following versions of jars:

- json-schema-validator-2.1.8
- json-schema-core-1.1.9
- jackson coreutils 1.5
- guava 16.0.1
- jackson databind 2.2.3
- jackson core 2.3.1
- jackson anno 2.3.1

.

```
final JsonNode fstabSchema=Utils.loadResource("Schemas/JsonSchema/"+serviceName+".json");
final JsonNode jsonResponse = Utils.loadResource("Response/Json/devices_search_2.json");
final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();

final JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(fstabSchema);

ProcessingReport report;
report=schema.validate(jsonResponse);
System.out.println(report);
```

I am getting this exception and I cant find out what I am missing. Any Help will be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/fge/Frozen
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at validate.jsonValidator(validate.java:55)
    at validate.main(validate.java:74)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.fge.Frozen
```

I am not using json-schema-core 1.0.2 ( stable version )  because the binary is not available and I am not using maven.

Comment: (hello, the author here) You are missing the `btf` jar. Also, I am surprised that the binary of 2.0.1 is not available. Where do you download from?

Comment: https://bintray.com/fge/maven/json-schema-core

Comment: See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.0.1) --> 2.0.1 is available, you can download the jar from there (and dependenciesà

Comment: Not only for json-schema-core also for json-schema-validator i didnt find the binary for the stable version. Anyways thanks !

Comment: Ah yes, only 2.1.x is available on bintray, so this is "normal"

Comment: Hello, I am seeing following error: cannot access Frozen
[ERROR] class file for com.github.fge.Frozen not found.                           I am using  
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>                                                           
 not sure what is causing the error. And advise.

Comment: Okay, I added the btf-1.2.jar dependency. The error was no longer seen.